# Object variable containing undeclared variable as value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a video game in Javascript, but I find myself stuck on making a function where you move between maps.

The way I have it set up is every map is an object containing values for everything in the map, and the new map you go to when moving to the left, right, up and down.

Example:

```js
map1 = { 
  rightScreen: map2;
}

map2 = {
  leftScreen: map1;
}
```

Problem is when I try to get from `map1` to `map2` it returns `undefined`, this is because `map2` is not yet defined.

I cannot put the `map2` variable on top either, because that causes the same problem to occur when going from `map2` to `map1`.

I've tried the hoisting method and `window['string']` among many other solutions, but none seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about moving `map1` and `map2` declaration on top like this:

```js
var map1 = {},
  map2 = {};

map1.rightScreen = map2;
map2.leftScreen = map1;
```

The idea is to basically get the variables initialized by empty objects and they setting the properties in the next statements. This way, you won't lose track of any of these.